# 2008 Malibu LTZ ECT sensor location

Tags: sensor, malibu, ect

Where is the engine coolant temperature sensor on my 2008 Malibu LTZ, with 2.4L Ecotec engine? I've checked online and can't seem to find a good video or guidance. I thought it would jump out at me once I removed the engine cover. No such luck. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the cover off, the sensor is located towards the back of the engine on the right side (as if you're sitting in the vehicle - passenger side for people in the States). I've clipped a couple of images from [this video](https://youtu.be/Iw3INhrQ8oU) (very crappy quality, but it gets the point across). It is for a 2011 Malibu, but seeing as how it's the same 2.4L Ecotec engine, location and all should be about the same.

[image]

The silver thing at the bottom of the image looks to be an exhaust shroud, but I'm not sure.

[image]

Dude was nice enough to tell us you'd need a 19mm deep well socket to get to it. This image shows the sensor with the plug disconnected. This image would be if you rolled over the engine a little farther into the engine compartment from the first image. Hopefully you can make out where it's at.